# SelectionChanged event not raised

Tags: wpf, events, selecteditem, selectionchanged

Is there a way to fix the known bug of Selection Change Event, selecting does not work if the same item is tapped again.

to give further background, my scenario is that I have four items in my pivot page and when I click one of those items i will be navigated to another page. Now my dilemma is that when i select the same items again, navigation does not work or nothing happens.

Please let me know your suggested fix, thanks much in advance.

```
  <ListBox x:Name="lbviewlist" ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="selectionchanged">
                        <Command:EventToCommand Command ="{Binding ItemListCommand }" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"  />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding itemName}"   FontSize="30"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" Foreground="CadetBlue"/>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding itemDescription}"   FontSize="20"  Margin="15,5,0,10"/>
                          </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Its not a bug, `SelectedChanged` does exactly what it should, it fires when the Selection changes, if the same element is selected it has not changed so it does not fire. You may have to handle this with one of the MouseEvents on your Item or the ListBox itself

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Kindly teach me how to do that? I'm just a newbie in this field and somehow has a hard time to understand the concept. Do you mean that I should change the selection change event to mouse events?I'm using MVVM by  the way

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative approach is to include all of the content in each item inside a button, which is styled to be invisible so that you never see it, but it covers the surface of the item it encapsulates. If you're using MVVM you can bind the same command property to each of your 'buttons' and bind the DataContext of the button (your data item) to the command parameter. Then whenever you click an item you'll get the command firing every time.
You might want to change your items control to something simple so that the selection changed events dont get in the way.

Comment: How can I include all the items inside the button and make it invisible? Please see my XAML above

Comment: I was able to put the content in a button however the event is not firing? Any idea?

Comment: Just to be clear, we're talking about the button 'click' event here, not the 'SelectionChanged' event of the combo box any more.